# How to refresh all providers in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

When user logout's from the app, I want to refresh all providers so that the previous user's data will not be stored on current users providers. Is there a global way to do this without using autodispose or ref.invalidate(provider) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one provider who is responsible for authorization (bool|false). All other providers watch it using `ref.watch` or `ref.listen`. As soon as the user logs out, the providers will rebuild themselves.